# Why cant I access my params using Express' Router() with 'GET' method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I have an overloaded fetch function on an Angular service 'PostSvc'
if a user is provided as an argument the idea is to only return that users posts. Otherwise fetch all posts from the database....

The user is an 'object' passed from the post.ctrl.js with the following keys

```
{
    username: $scope.currentUser,
    body: $scope.postBody,
    user_id: $scope.currentUser._id
}
```

this is giving me the _id field mongodb/mongoose generate as expected

```
console.log($scope.currentUser._id)
```

Here's the Mongoose Post model:

```
var db = require('../db')

var Post = db.model('Post', {
    username : { type: String, required: true },
    body : { type: String, required: true },
    user_id: { type: String, required: true },
    date : { type: String, required: true, default: Date.now },
})

module.exports = Post
```

Here's a snippet from the server.js file assigning the router:

```
app.use("/api/posts", require("./controllers/api/posts"))
```

Here's the Express './controllers/api/post.js' Router:

```
var Post = require('../../models/post')

var router = require('express').Router()

var websockets = require('../../websockets')


// this route works just fine
// returns All posts from the db
//
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
    // find all posts from db
    //
    Post.find()
    .sort("-date")
    .exec(function(err, posts) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        res.json(posts)
        next()
    })
})
```

## the probelem....

```
router.get("/:user_id", function(req, res, next) {
    var query = {}

    // these messages aren't being logged to console
    // so there's no way the route is being used
    console.log("from the get 'api/posts' method" )
    console.dir(req.params.user_id)

    if (req.params.user_id) {
        query = { user_id: req.params.user_id } // sent from posts.svc.js
    }
    // this query is not executing properly
    // I have no access to the `req.params.user_id`
    // 
    Post.find({ user_id: req.params.user_id })
    .sort("-date")
    .exec(function(err, posts) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        res.json(posts)
        next()
    })
})

router.post("/", function(req, res, next) {
    var post = new Post({ body: req.body.body })
    if (!req.auth) { return res.sendStatus(401) }
    post.username = req.auth.username
    post.user_id = req.body.user_id
    post.save(function(err, post) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        websockets.broadcast("new_post", post)
        res.status(201).json(post)
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

And last but not least here is the Angular Service that sends the initial 'GET' request to the 'server.js' -> './controllers/api/posts.js' and awaits the response:

```
angular.module("app").service('PostsSvc', function($http) {
    this.fetch = function(user) {
        var credentials = {}
        if (user) {
            credentials = user

            // checkpoint
            //
            console.dir("from the fetch function " + credentials._id)
            // only return authencated users posts
            return $http.get("/api/posts", {
                params: {
                    user_id: credentials._id // to the posts.js router
                }
            })


            // return all posts otherwise
        } else { return $http.get("/api/posts") }


    }

    this.create = function(post) {
        return $http.post("/api/posts", post)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have being in this same trouble with the `router.get` in express. The body is empty. I finally turned to use instead a `router.post()` which worked perfectly for me, as long as you also call the api with a post request whit angular.

Comment: As it turns out the parameters were actually on the query object of the request